# How to find out how much i/o resources a task, session, request or transaction is currently using?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, monitoring, dmv, wait-types

How to find out how much i/o resources a task, session, request or transaction is currently using?

by task I mean the DMV called [DMV sys.dm_os_tasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174963(v=sql.110).aspx).
by session I mean the DMV sys.dm_exec_sessions

Sometimes a session has a request, by request I mean the DMV [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648(v=sql.120).aspx)
or a session might have a transaction instead - [sys.dm_tran_database_transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186957(v=sql.110).aspx)

How can I link these things with **I/O usage**?

I had a look at the DMV called [DMV sys.dm_os_tasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174963(v=sql.110).aspx) .

The [DMV sys.dm_os_tasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174963(v=sql.110).aspx) has some interesting columns to find out more about processes currently running in sql server.

*sys.dm_os_tasks - not showing pending_io_byte_count*

However, when I try to identify how much I/O each of my tasks is dealing with the pending I/O in bytes is always zero.

[image]

This is an example of the results of my query while I was trying to monitor some CXPACKETS WAITS.

Pending_IO_count seems to be fine, but pending_IO_by_counts are always zero.

what could be an alternative?
I want to measure the I/O usage of each parallel process.

in fact it could be just the I/O usage of each session or request.

even sessions without request sometimes are good to see, because they might be blocking other processes.

[image]

Comment: Those are physical I/O tasks, so I'm not sure they would report logical I/O. In other words, if the page is already in memory, then there is no pending I/O.

Comment: good point- but then how can I find the disk i/o on the current processes, either linking to requests, sessions or transactions

Comment: Have you looked at the sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats DMV?

Comment: I think that will be the way after all. what I really wanted is per object rather than per file. I know this could be mapped, but not exclusively of an object in particular, unless the object is the only object in a file.

Comment: The XML showplan has the 'ActualPhysicalReads' element, maybe you could parse this out? http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan/

Comment: I think that is a great idea! You can put this as an answer. How to implement? that would be another question, but it seems to be doable, and useful in my case.

Comment: I can't post an answer at the moment, but I believe that there are 1 or 2 DMVs that might get you "current" info.

Comment: that is the info I am after ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the actual physical I/O for a query, you should look in the XML showplan for the 'ActualPhysicalReads' element:

[schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan)

However, those physical reads are likely only going to occur the first time the plan is cached. Subsequent runs are more likely to pull the pages from memory, not from disk.

HTH

Comment: Just curious how this answers the question. The plan wouldn't parse out what is _currently_ running.

Comment: @srutzky - you are correct - it doesnt 100% answer the question. I am not even sure I will be able to achieve what I wanted, but this question gave me a possibility that I want to work on at a later time.